# "Canvas is null" error in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

This is the code, (don't kill me, i've just started to study javascript)...Firefox'errors console returns me the error "Canvas is null" but i don't understandwhy. I guess that maybe it could be cause i've passed the variable id in a bad way.

```
<html>
<canvas id="c1">
Your browser doesn't support canvas!
</canvas>

<video style="display:none;" id="video1" controls height="600px" width="800px" >
<source src="videos/movie.mp4" type="vide/mp4" >
<source src="videos/movie.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'/>
<source src="videos/movie.webm" type='video/webm' >
</video>


<script type="text/javascript">

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

    video = document.getElementById("video1");
    video.height = 600;
    video.width = 400;
    video.play();
    aggiornacanvas("c1");

    function aggiornacanvas(id) {
        canvas = document.getElementById(id);
        canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d");
        canvasContext.drawImage(video, 0, 0);
        data = canvasContext.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        //Modificare qui i dati dell'immagine
        canvasContext.putImageData(data, 0, 0);
        setTimeout(aggiornacanvas, 0);

    }




}, false);    


</script>
</html>
```

Ok, now it works but there is another errors

```
function aggiornacanvas(id)
{
    canvas = document.getElementById(id);
    canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvasContext.drawImage(video,0,0);
    var data = canvasContext.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    alert("ok");    
    canvasContext.putImageData(data,0,0);
    setTimeout(aggiornacanvas(id),40);

}
```

In this way it not works, and i get ok only one time...but if i write

```
function aggiornacanvas(id)
{
    canvas = document.getElementById(id);
    canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvasContext.drawImage(video,0,0);
    //var data = canvasContext.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    alert("ok");    
    //canvasContext.putImageData(data,0,0);
    setTimeout(aggiornacanvas(id),40);

}
```

it works!The problem is that i think that lines are correnct so i can't understand why it doesn't work whit them :(

UPDATED It works!That was a problem of browser that don't allow to access at imagedata locally! THANKS guys, my first question on there it's been answered!

Comment: is DOMContentLoaded event cross browser? Try to change it to addEventListener('load',function())

Comment: i'm using firefox and i'm pretty sure that DOMContentLoaded is compatible whit it

Comment: I don't think this is the issue here, but please, please use `var` statements! It will save you many headaches in Javascript.

Comment: There's no reason to refetch the canvas element by id every frame! Save that in a variable before you go to work, outside your functions. (Through the magic of _closures_ it will be available inside the function.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `aggiornacanvas` from your `setTimeout`, but `aggiornacanvas` requires a parameter - the `id` of your `canvas` element.  Since that parameter is missing, your variable `canvas` is `null`.  Hence, the error.

Change your `setTimeout` to call `aggiornacanvas` with a parameter by wrapping it in an anonymous function.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    aggiornacanvas(id);
}, 0);
```

But, holy smokes!  Don't do that!  This will call `aggiornacanvas` over and over without stopping and spike your CPU!  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i'm trying to do some stuff whit canvas only for exercise ;)

Comment: I mean, what are you trying to do by calling `setTimeout` recursively with a timeout value of `0`?  Besides test your CPU performance...

Comment: updating video, but i guess i can set it at 30 or 40 cause i don't need all this urgency, it's an error...

but there is an other error...

Comment: @DxW - Your updated code should not be working since you are calling the function immediately instead of passing a function reference (ie, wrapping the function call in an anonymous function as suggested in my answer).  In your "working" example do you get the alert just twice or do you get it repeatedly?

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
setTimeout(aggiornacanvas, 0);
```

is causing `aggiornacanvas` function to be called without a parameter. The first time run, canvas is not `null`. The second time, it is, and the script quits. If you change this to:

```
setTimeout(function(){aggiornacanvas('c1')}, 0);
```

there won't be a null error and `aggiornacanvas` will be called repeatedly. No comment on design here, but it may be improved with others' suggestions.

Comment: That is not right.  `setTimeout` requires a function reference.  You are making a function call which returns `undefined`.  The function will be called immediately and you'll get a stack overflow.

Comment: Can u tell me these suggestions please? :(